# Robot Framework - Wait until a form textfield contains text

Tags: robotframework, textfield, wait

For my tests I need to wait until a form textfield is filled with text and I want to check that text. It's a address form which automatically fills the street and city based on postalcode.

Using "Wait until element contains" does not work for me and I want to avoid using a sleep and then use "textfield should contain" because of variable timings.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with “does not work”. What you describe is the intended functionality of `Wait until Element Contains`.

Comment: The keyword does not see the text apearing and waits until the timeout is passed. If I check it with "Textfield should contain" with the same locator it finds the text.

Comment: I had similar issue.  I found [Wait for condition](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Wait%20For%20Condition) to be a simple way to check that form inputs have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using this, with the help of @Todor:

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    1min    1s    Textfield Should Contain    Fieldname    Value
```

Answer (score 3):

The `Wait Until Element Contains` does not work for you, as it "waits" for the element's text to have the desired value - that's stated [in the documentation](http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Wait%20Until%20Element%20Contains).

In the same time, the `Textfield Should Contain` works on `<input>` html elements, and checks their `value` *attribute* (this is what stores the text set by the user). As it does work for you, your target element is an `<input>` one, right?

In order to get the `value`, you should use the keyword `Get Element Attribute` to get the attribute's value; to wait until it is updated, you can wrap it in `Wait Until Keyword Succeeds` - here's the latter's [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Wait%20Until%20Keyword%20Succeeds).

A rough sample:

```
*** Test Cases ***
Check the value is correct
    Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    retry=10s    retry_interval=200ms    The value of the input should be    expected text
    # will check the value of the input every 200ms, and continue if it matches "expected text"
    # if it does not matches in 10 seconds, the keyword and the case will be failed.

*** Keywords ***
The value of the input should be
    [Arguments]    ${expected}
    ${actual value}=    Get Element Attribute    locator_for_the_element    value
    Should Be Equal As Strings    ${actual value}    ${expected}
```

Comment: Thanks! With your solution I crafted my own, see below

Answer (score 0):

You can use Element Should Contain Keyword
`Element Should Contain  xpath=//div[@class="clr"] sampleText`